# Azure AD GraphServiceClient Extensions not working

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the following query to retrieve a User using the `GraphServiceClient` with .net core 2.

```
 user = await _graphClient.Users[principalName].Request()
                    .Expand("Extensions")
                    .GetAsync();
```

When I run this I get the following error

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException Message:
>   Unexpected exception returned from the service.

This only happens when I have added a `OpenTypeExtension` to the user using the following code!

```
extension = new OpenTypeExtension
                {
                    ExtensionName = AzureADExtensions.UserConstants.ExtensionName,
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"OtherEmail", externalUser.Email},
                        {"OtherRole" , externalUser.Roles.FirstOrDefault()}
                    }
                };

                await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Extensions.Request()
                    .AddAsync(extension);
```

I am starting to get really getting fed up with Azure AD now.

I can't seem to add any meta data to my users. Only doing this because `otherEmails` does not work with the `GraphServiceClient` and trying to use any other sensible fields gives me this error:

> Tenant does not have a SPO license when updating user

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone else that come across this, it seems to be an a bug in the service client.

The code below fails

```
  user = await _graphClient
                    .Users[userId]
                    .Request()
                    .Expand("Extensions")
                    .GetAsync();
```

But this code works, just by requesting the extensions in a separate call!

```
 user = await _graphClient
                    .Users[userId]
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();

                var extensions = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();
                user.Extensions = extensions;
```

Hope that save's someone the time I lost on this!