# Azure AD GraphServiceClient can't set AdditionalData against User

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the GraphServiceClient with .Net Core 2. I am trying to add AdditionalData to my Users using the following code

```
var updated = new User()
                {
                   AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"OtherEmail", otherEmail},
                        {"OtherRole", otherRole}
                    },
                };

                await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(updated);
```

When this executes I get the following error

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: Request_BadRequest Message:
>   One or more property values specified are invalid.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Also if anyone can please tell me how I can just save some of my own metadata against a user it would be really appreciated. I have also tried using the extensions, but I am having this problem.

[Azure AD GraphServiceClient Extensions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670019/azure-ad-graphserviceclient-extensions-not-working)

Comment: Are you using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) or [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations) to do this?

Comment: I am using the GraphServiceClient in Microsoft.Graph. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got around this using OpenExtensions, this also caused me a lot of issues, which can be seen here.

[Azure AD GraphServiceClient Extensions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670019/azure-ad-graphserviceclient-extensions-not-working/53707315#53707315)

Trick is to add the extensions like this

```
extension = new OpenTypeExtension
                {
                    ExtensionName = AzureADExtensions.UserConstants.ExtensionName,
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"OtherEmail", externalUser.Email},
                        {"OtherRole" , externalUser.Roles.FirstOrDefault()}
                    }
                };

                await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Extensions.Request()
                    .AddAsync(extension);
```

And then retrieve them like this.

```
user = await _graphClient
                    .Users[userId]
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();
// Note : you should be able to expand this on original request, but fails for me.
                var extensions = await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();
                user.Extensions = extensions;
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: What is `AzureADExtensions.UserConstants.ExtensionName` ?

Answer (score 5):

To add attributes to the `AdditionalData` field you have to define the attribute in *Azure AD B2C > User attributes* (in the Azure portal).  If you for example create a *Boolean* attribute `Dummy`, this will create the field `extension_{b2c-extensions-app-id}_Dummy` where `{b2c-extensions-app-id}` is the *Application ID* of the automatically generated `b2c-extensions-app` viewable by navigating to *Azure AD B2C > App registrations (Preview) > b2c-extensions-app* **with the dashes (`-`) removed from the ID**!

This would allow you to do the following:

```cs
var updated = new User()
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"extension_0000000000000000000000000000_Dummy", false}
        },
    };

await _graphClient.Users[user.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(updated);
```

Comment: Perfect answer thanks. I highlighted the the part where it says **Remove `-`** Since I was not doing that and tried to make it work for hours... :D