# Use Azure AD B2C GraphClient to set AdditionalData against User in Javascript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Much like the person that asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671020/azure-ad-graphserviceclient-cant-set-additionaldata-against-user) I have an app that manages Azure AD B2C users. I am trying to do the same thing as that guy which is add a user that has a custom attribute. The difference is I am trying to do this in Javascript/Typescript but I am not having any luck. The code I am struggling with converting is the Dictionary object:

```
AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"OtherEmail", externalUser.Email},
}
```

I have no problem creating other users without the 'AdditionalData' attribute, but when I add that attribute to the code I am trying to execute I get the following error:

```
{"message": "A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value."}
```

Here is my code for creating a user:

```
  const batchIDAttributeName = CreateCustomAttribute("AttName"); //extension_<b2c extension client id>_AttName

  const user = {
    givenName: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe',
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    identities: [
      {
        signInType: "userName",
        issuer: <my tenant>,
        issuerAssignedId: 'JDoe',
      },
    ],
    passwordProfile: {
      password: 'password',
      forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false,
    },
    additionalData: {
      [batchIDAttributeName]: 201522154
    },
    passwordPolicies: "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
    accountEnabled: true,
    mail: "",
  };

  var result = await client.api("/users").post(user);
```

I have also tried:

```
additionalData: {
  key: [batchIDAttributeName],
  value: 201522154
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am sure that I can't be that far off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `additionalData` when creating a user with custom properties.

**HTTP**:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

{
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "displayName": "Adele Vance",
    "mailNickname": "AdeleV",
    "userPrincipalName": "AdeleV@<b2c-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "passwordProfile": {
        "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
        "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
    },
    "extension_<b2c-extensions-app client id without the dashes '-'>_AttName": "123456"
}
```

**JavaScript** with [the MS Graph sample](https://github.com/leeford/MSGraphAppAccessToken):

```
// create Users from Graph
async function createUsers(): Promise<any> {

    const client = createAuthenticatedClient();

    const user = {
        accountEnabled: true,
        displayName: "Adele Vance3",
        mailNickname: "AdeleV3",
        userPrincipalName: "AdeleV3@<b2c-tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com",
        "passwordProfile" : {
          forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: true,
          password: "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
        },
        "extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_AttName": "123456"
      };
      
    const request = await client.api("/users")
        .post(user)
        .catch((error) => {

            console.log(error);

        });

    console.log(request.value);

}

createUsers();
```

[image]